# How can I pass a value from the backend to a React frontend and use that value in the CSS for the frontend?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend

I'm using Python as the backend for my React frontend and right now my backend is passing in values like `17` or `87` and I want to use that value as a percentage in the scale I'm building. Right now, you can see that the scale starts in the middle:

[image]

And it doesn't move anywhere because the backend hasn't given it a number yet. But if the backend gave a score of `23`, the triangle would move to exactly 23% of the div (outlined in the black border):

[image]

Here is the code in the HTML part of my React frontend:

```js
<div
  className={
    !this.state.listening
      ? 'results-container'
      : 'results-container-closed'
  }
>
  <div className="result-wrapper">
    {this.state.score === ''
      ? 'Click record and check your score'
      : 'Your Score: ' + this.state.score}
  </div>
</div>

<div className="scale-container">
  <div className="bar">
    <div className="arrow-up"></div>
    <div className="scale-meter"></div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

`this.state.score` is where the score is stored when I get it from the backend.

This is my CSS:

```
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 25px solid purple;

  animation: scale 4s ease;
}

@keyframes scale {
  from {
    left: 48%;
  }
}
.bar:nth-child(1) .arrow-up{
  left: 23%;
}
```

The `.bar:nth-child(1) .arrow-up` part is where I want the `left` to be changed based on the score. Is there a way I can make it so that instead of me hardcoding the `left` value, it can be something like `left: score%;`?

Comment: make python template the value into its own inline `<script>` as some `const initialLoadPercentage = {{ perc }};` and have React read those values on componentDidMount?

Comment: You can just use inline styling for the left attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inline styling where `this.state.score` will be your value for `left` property:

```js
style={{ left: `${this.state.score}%` }}
```

You can use back-ticks to concatenate % string with `score` value at the end:

```js
<div
  className={
    !this.state.listening
      ? 'results-container'
      : 'results-container-closed'
  }
>
  <div className="result-wrapper">
    {this.state.score === ''
      ? 'Click record and check your score'
      : 'Your Score: ' + this.state.score}
  </div>
</div>

<div className="scale-container">
  <div className="bar">
    <div className="arrow-up" style={{ left: `${this.state.score}%` }}></div>
    <div className="scale-meter"></div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I do that inline style, the bar (like the purple bar itself) also moves to the left by whatever the score is, do you know how to make it so that only the arrow moves?

Comment: Yes, sorry. My bad, i will edit my answer. It is set now to `arrow-up`

Comment: Thank you so much by the way, I had one more question. Right now I'm getting my score from talking into my mic (using react speech-recognition), the website then takes the transcript and scores it using an API, and then it spits that score out to the frontend. For some reason, when I do this, the score doesn't update, like the arrow on the screen doesn't move. But when I manually do it, it updates fine. Would you happen to know why this happens?

Comment: You can post another question regarding that, since it is a different issue, or just edit this one to have one more section. I can't figure it out off the top, need to see some code. If you are subscribing to a event from that lib, setting state should be done easily.

Comment: Hello again, I just wanted to tell you that I posted another question regarding it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70646685/why-is-my-backend-not-sending-the-value-to-the-frontend, if you figure out why that happens I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks